# Value returned by getText() method in Java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

When I type nothing in the TextField which uses getText() method. What will be the value fetched.?

```
String s = jTextField1.getText();
if(s==null)
{
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"No Input");
}
```

Is the value null?

Comment: I think it returns an empty `""` String.

Comment: Well why don't you test it out........ ?

Comment: null doesnt work.nor ""

Comment: It neither throws an exception.

Comment: @Koneri Not throwing an exception is ... well ... normal behaviour. This code is way too simple for it too throw an exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `JTextField` with nothing it will typically return an empty `String`...

```
String s = jTextField1.getText();
if (s.isEmpty()) {...}
```

However, a `JTextField` may not always be completely empty and may contain spaces, if you it matters to you you can use...

```
String s = jTextField1.getText();
if (s.trim().isEmpty()) {...}
```

instead, for example

Comment: Yup. Works. Thank You

Answer (score 1):

If you follow the source code of `getText()`, you will get to this method:

```
/**
 * Retrieves a portion of the content.  where + len must be <= length().
 *
 * @param where the starting position >= 0
 * @param len the length to retrieve >= 0
 * @return a string representing the content; may be empty
 * @exception BadLocationException if the specified position is invalid
 * @see AbstractDocument.Content#getString
 */
public String getString(int where, int len) throws BadLocationException {
    if (where + len > count) {
        throw new BadLocationException("Invalid range", count);
    }
    return new String(data, where, len);
}
```

in the class `javax.swing.text.StringContent`.

So the answer is: **No**. It won't return **null**. It will return an empty `String`.